# Mostrar imágenes sin repetirlas Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

Hola Developers estoy tratando de mostrar imagenes desde la carpeta Drawable pero cuando corro el codigo las imagenes se repiten. como puedo remover las imagenes que ya visualicé???

```
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    textView_help = findViewById(R.id.textView_help);


    textView_help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Randomimage();

        }
    });





}

private void Randomimage() {



    int [] images = {

            R.drawable.avion,
            R.drawable.carro,
            R.drawable.madera,
            R.drawable.dormir,
            R.drawable.latop,
            R.drawable.puerta
    };



    Random random = new Random();
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[random.nextInt(images.length)]);





     }



}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que se repiten?

Comment: Por ejemplo cuando hago click se van cambiando las imágenes, pero si la imagen del avión fue la primera después que pasa la imágen del carro vuelve aparecer, yo quiero que se vayan removiendo las imágenes que ya se han visto en el ImageView.

Comment: Dejame entender, ¿Dices que al presionar el TextView se debe cambiar la imagen pero no se debe volver a repetir, verdad? Esta condición, ¿Solo aplica cuando estas en esa pantalla? ¿O si cierro la app no me tienen que volver a salir las imágenes que ya vi?

Comment: La condicion solo se debe cumplir cuando haga click y este usando esa vista. Ya que al cerrar la app todo empezaría de nuevo , osea no importa si despues de cerrar la app todo vuelve a la normalidad

Comment: @Osdward Quieres que se muestre una imagen aleatoriamente pero que no se repita durante la sesión ?

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución para lo que buscas, es la siguiente. Primero creamos una variable global y el arreglo con las imágenes:

```
private int imagenActual = 0; 
int[] imagenes = { R.drawable.avion, R.drawable.carro, R.drawable.madera, R.drawable.dormir, R.drawable.latop, R.drawable.puerta };
```

Luego, creamos tu función:

```
private void cambioDeImagen(){
  imagenActual++; //creamos el contador
  imagenActual = imagenActual % imagenes.length; 
  imageView.setImageResource(imagenes[imagenActual]); //luego la ponemos de fondo según su posición
}
```

Y por último, la llamas en tu evento:

```
    textView_help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        cambioDeImagen(){};
    }
});

Me comentas que tal
```

Comment: He notado que funciona y que las imagenes e muestran en orden y cuando recorre el array vuelve a donde empezo.

Comment: ¿Ha solucionado entonces tu problema?

Comment: Mas o menos, ya que el plan es que sea aleatorio sin repetir hasta que recorra el array.